# How to input new instance of Object with multiple arguments into NSMutablearray

Tags: objective-c, initialization, nsmutablearray

I'm very new to Obj-C, been learning more Java and C++ lately.
I have two objects Friend and Foe which inherit the Character Object. Friend and Foe have slightly different attributes. I want all Friends and Foes to be in the same NSMutablearray. Can't figure out how to put these into the array. I get an error saying too many arguments, expected 1 have 4. For Foe its the same, but expected 1, have 5.

The Character Object

```
#import <foundation/foundation.h>
@interface Character : NSObject
@property NSString *name;
@property NSInteger strength;
@property NSInteger iff;
- (void) printDetails;
@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "game_character.h"
@implementation Character
- (void) printDetails
{
NSLog (@"%@ has strength %ld\n", self.name, self.strength);
}
@end
```

The Friend Object (The Foe object is similar with without intelligence and spell but has an alternate NSInteger attribute.

```
@interface Friend : Character
@property NSInteger intelligence;
@property NSString *spell;
- (void)printDetails;
@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "game_character.h"
#import "friend.h"
@implementation Friend
-(void)printDetails
{
NSLog (@"%@ has strength %ld\n", self.name, self.strength);
NSLog (@" ,Intelligence %ld, Spell %@\n", self.intelligence, self.spell);
}
@end
```

The Friend Input Method (I will have a similar method to input a Foe)

```
void input_friend()
{
@autoreleasepool
{
    char str[30] = {0};
    NSInteger strength;
    NSInteger iff=1;
    NSInteger intelligence;
    NSLog(@"Enter character name\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];

    NSLog(@"Enter character strength\n");
    scanf("%ld", &strength);
    NSLog(@"Enter character intelligence");
    scanf("%ld", &intelligence);
    NSLog(@"Enter character spell\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    NSString *spell = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:str];
```

My Error is here when I try to add the object to the array.

```
    [characters addObject:name, strength, iff, intelligence, spell];
}
}
```

The Main so far. I intend to add a menu with option to add Friend or Foe to the array.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool
{
    characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    void input_friend();
    void input_foe();

}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, you are passing multiple arguments to add to your list of characters. However, this doesn't work since you want to add objects, which is why you got your error:

```
[characters addObject:name, strength, iff, intelligence, spell];
```

So you need to initialize a new Friend or Foe first, set its properties, and then add it to your array.

```
Friend *newFriend = [[Friend alloc] init];
newFriend.name = name;
newFriend.strength = strength;
// etc.

[characters addObject: newFriend];
```

Comment: I added your code with the properties and removed etc. and now it's saying. Use of undeclared identifier Friend and newFriend.

Comment: You probably want to add `#import Friend.h` at the top of the file where you use this code.

Comment: Also, make sure to use the correct capitalization in your code, for instance `#import <foundation/foundation.h>` should be `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`, etc.

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I hadn't imported them (facepalm!). Thanks again I just spotted the f's there myself :)

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. See also here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I want to print the details of each character in the array. I'm having a little trouble with it. I made a method for each character called printDetails(); but I'm having trouble putting it in a loop with the mutable array. How would I do it?

Comment: I recommend making a new question for this.

Comment: I'm at the question limit after 1 question.

Comment: Then you need to find out how you can post again, sorry I cannot help you with that.